# Quick MSDN Search in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search, msdn

Is there a way to get an MSDN search bar in Firefox **which will autocomplete .Net class and member names** (and preferably also Win32 API methods) and take me directly to the MSDN page?

Google toolbar with Shift+Enter (I'm feeling lucky) will usually go directly to the msdn page for a .Net class,  but it doesn't have targeted autocomplete.  Also, since I'm too lazy to type `site:msdn.microsoft.com`, it doesn't always take me to MSDN.  (eg, `Graphics`)

Comment: searching it quicker won't make it better though :(

Comment: Just to address your "too lazy to type site:..." remark: you can create keyword searches for the address bar in firefox. Go to Google, right click on the search box and select "Add a keyword for this search..." Enter something like 'MSDN' in the keyword field. Next, edit the bookmark you just created (keywords are bookmarks) and edit the URL to include the 'site:' filter. Something like "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%s%20site:msdn.microsoft.com" should work.

Comment: I guess SO doesn't completely display links in comments. The link points to the right place though.

Comment: Unfortunately, a keyword search will not have autocompletion.

Comment: I know. That's why I posted it as a comment addressing only that minor point, rather than as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This search plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/48986) (from the list flyfishr64 linked to) works quite well (suggestions and everything).

Comment: It goes to a search results page instead of directly to the first result.

Answer (score 7):

There are several [msdn search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=msdn&cat=all&advancedsearch=1&as=1&appid=1&lver=3.5&atype=0&pp=20&pid=5&sort=&lup=) providers available.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a bookmark with a wildcard `%s` and the `msdn` keyword by using the following url for the bookmarked page:

`http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us/?query=%s`

Now in the address bar, when I type "msdn StringBuilder" it brings me to this result page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us/?query=StringBuilder

I did the same with the `stackoverflow` keyword and the `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%s` url.

EDIT: as @AgentConundrum pointed out, using the `http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%s%20site:msdn.microsoft.com` url will restrict Google search to the `msdn.microsoft.com` site.

Comment: I just made this comment on the question, after having decided against posting it as it's own answer. I'm gonna cry when you're upvoted. :P

Comment: I thought of this.  However, it wouldn't give autocomplete.

Comment: No, since great minds talk alike, you'll upvote me happily :)

Comment: This might even be improved by adding `site:msdn.microsoft.com` to the query as suggested by AgentConundrum: google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%s%20site:msdn.microsoft.com%22

Answer (score 1):

I ended up editing [this search plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/48986) from [Shog9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022710/quick-msdn-search-in-firefox/2022790#2022790) and changing the search URL to Google's I'm Feeling Lucky.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
    <!-- Created on Thu, 07 Jan 2010 15:11:13 GMT -->
    <ShortName>MSDN</ShortName>
    <Description>Search MSDN documentation</Description>
    <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&amp;q={searchTerms}+site%3Amsdn.microsoft.com&amp;btnI=I"/>
    <Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" template="http://services.social.microsoft.com/search//Data/AutoCompleteTerms?t={searchTerms}&amp;b=Msdn&amp;l=en-US&amp;m=10&amp;rf=oss10"/>
    <Image width="16" height="16">http://mycroft.mozdev.org/updateos.php/id0/msdn_schnore.ico</Image>
    <Developer>Schabse Laks</Developer>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    <moz:SearchForm>http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/</moz:SearchForm>
    <Url type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" rel="self" template="http://mycroft.mozdev.org/updateos.php/id0/msdn_schnore.xml"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```